# How to pass multiple list(hlist) as function arguments in C

Tags: c, arguments, double-pointer

```
hlist_t hlist[4];

int hlist_init (hlist_t **hlist) {
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 4 ; i++) {
    INIT_HLIST_HEAD ( hlist [i]);
    }

    return 1;
}



int main () {
    hlist_init (&hlist);

    return 0;
}
```

I have code like this but it doesn't work.
parameter as * hlist[] also doesn't work. 
How should I handle it?
and how **hlist and *hlist[] is different?

below is the error message of code. 
/media/hdd1/tcn/lbtest/main.c:20:5: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘hlist_init’ from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
/media/hdd1/tcn/lbtest/main.c:6:5: note: expected ‘struct hlist_t **’ but argument is of type ‘struct hlist_t (*)[4]’

Comment: How does it "doesn't work", what's the error, details?

Comment: `hlist_t **hlist` is a pointer to pointer to `hlist_t` and `hlist_t *hlist[]` is an unidentified length of array of pointer to `hlist_t`. They will make no difference as function argument because array declaration in function parameter will be converted to pointer to its elements.

Comment: Do post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), please.

Comment: In the context of a function's parameter list `hlist_t ** hlist` and `hlist_t * hlist[]` are equivalent.

Comment: I add some codes and it's error message! Thank you for your help! @MikeCAT

Answer (score 0):

In a function parameter list, `**hlist` and `*hlist[]` are perfectly identical. So changing one to the other won't make any difference.

This is because C has "array decay", that is, in most cases, an array name decays to the pointer to its first element. Thus, whether you are using `**hlist` or `*hlist[]`, the whole array is not copied. So you cannot pass the array by writing `foo(hlist);` in either case.

Seems that you expect `hlist` to be an array of pointer to hlist_t. If so, do:

```
hlist_t *hlist[4];
```